# Abrir o Outlook ao clicar num e-mail no componente TDBGrid no Delphi

Tags: delphi, email

Estou fazendo um utilitário onde vai ter o nome do funcionário, seu ramal e seu email.
Gostaria que ao clicar no e-mail já abrisse o Outlook. Como isso seria possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione a unit shellapi e tente isso, no evento CellClick. Troque o 'CAMPO EMAIL' pelo nome do seu campo, maiúsculo se for o caso.

```
    procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
    begin

      if (Column.Field.Name = 'CAMPO EMAIL') then
      begin

        ShellExecute(handle, 'open', pchar('mailto:' + Column.Field.Value), nil, nil, sw_ShowNormal);

      end;


    end;
```

Comment: Como faço para adicionar a unit shellapi? Desculpe a pergunta, mais sou iniciante.

Comment: achei o códido da unit shellapi. Adicionei ela, mas esta com um erro ainda.

Comment: [dcc32 Error] mainRamais.pas(70): E2089 Invalid typecast

Comment: [dcc32 Fatal Error] Utilitarios_KVA.dpr(5): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'mainRamais.pas'

Comment: Você está colocando a ShellApi em seu uses ou tentando copiar o código dela para seu aplicativo? É só adicionar no uses...

Comment: eu adicionei ela em meu uses, e criei uma unit com o codigo que achei em um site

Comment: Então, para executar o que te passei, basta adicionar a ShellApi no uses, e mais nada... Teve algum motivo em especial para vc usar um outro código?

Comment: achei o erro, deu certo. usei Winapi.ShellAPI no uses, e alterei pchar para PWideChar

Comment: sabe me dizer como faço para alterar o ícone do mouse somente no email ?

Comment: Opa legal, que bom ter ajudado... Sobre o mouse, pelas regras o certo seria você postar outra pergunta, tudo bem? abraços

Answer (score 0):

Algum tempo atrás eu tive uma necessidade similar e consegui resolver com [base nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8464058/2534489) do Sertac Akyuz no SOEN que utiliza o método [MailItem.Display](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff861853.aspx).

Basicamente você precisa declarar a unit `ComObj` e criar uma função como esta:

```delphi
procedure TFrmExemplo.EnviarEmail(Destinatario, Assunto, Mensagem: string;
  Anexo: TFileName);
var
  Outlook: OleVariant;
  Mail: Variant;
const
  olMailItem = $00000000;
begin
  try
    Outlook := GetActiveOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  except
    Outlook := CreateOleObject('Outlook.Application');
  end;
  Mail := Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem);
  Mail.to := Destinatario;
  Mail.Subject := Assunto;
  Mail.Body := Mensagem;
  if Anexo <> EmptyStr then
    Mail.Attachments.Add(Anexo);
  Mail.Display;
end;
```

Uma vez criada basta chamar o `Event Handler` que mais lhe parecer adequado, como o `OnCellClick`.

Vale notar que para que o método funcione é necessário que a máquina possua o Outlook instalado. Eu ainda não testei no Windows 8 mas acredito que funcione apenas com o Outlook para Desktop.

Comment: Opa, legal... Eu tava tentando lembrar dessa dica aí para ajudar o amigo, mas na hora lembrei o código inteiro... Desse jeito é melhor pois dá para compor a mensagem inteira ;)